# What is the token that represents a simple assignment (=) in PHP?

Tags: php, token

I was expecting to find a simple `T_EQUAL` or `T_ASSIGN` to be the token for `=` [here in PHP's parser token list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php), but it's nonexistent.

What token is used to express an assignment operation then? Say I have `$x = 1;`, It starts out with `T_VARIABLE`, followed by `T_WHITESPACE`, then the `=`, followed by whatever token a number falls under, then it's finished with a `;`. What token is used to represent these characters?

Comment: @Dagon Why not? I'm assuming it is because `=` is a single character, whereas all of the other tokens are made up of multiple characters.  Your comment could use some expansion.

Comment: I suppose you need not token list, but opcode list: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.assign.php

Comment: hmm I just leaned something new! I am not much of a help here Antilogical, but thanks to your post I now have something to read. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run this code:

```
var_dump(token_get_all('<?php $foo = "bar"; ?>'));
```

You'll see that `=` and `;` are not tokens.

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) says that `token_get_all` returns "...either a single character (i.e.: **;**, **.**, **>**, **!**, etc...), or a three element array containing the token index in element 0, the string content of the original token in element 1 and the line number in element 2." The way I interpret this, single characters are not tokens.

Although you'll probably notice on the "[List of Parser Tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)" page that the `T_NS_SEPARATOR` token (i.e. a backslash) is a single character. However, since PHP is written in C, and since a character array in C containing only a backslash is actually two characters (i.e. `"\\"`), that token is not actually a single character underneath the hood. This is just my theory for the explanation.

Comment: @Antilogical I updated by answer with an explanation of why it's not a token (at least my theory) in case you're curious.